# How to add regex for any path after / in nginx static content config?

Tags: regex, http, nginx, nginx-location

In my use case, I would like to provide static content from nginx based on a regex.

I.Here is my location mapping,

```
location ^\/static\/(.*)$ {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index /file.html;
}
```

So when I hit the endpoint /static/abcde  But this configuration is trying to find the file in `/usr/share/nginx/html/static/abcde/index.html`

I also tried with `alias` instead of `root`. But no luck.

II. Instead I tried the following configuration as well.

```
location /static {
    location ~\/(.*)$ {
    alias   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index /file.html;
    }
}
```

In this case, when I hit the endpoint `<HOST>/static/abcde` , it is giving 301 permanently moved. But `<HOST>/static/abcde/` is working fine. I mean without trailing `/` it is giving error. But I dont want the trailing `/`.

Could someone help me with this? I appreciate your help.

Comment: What's your intended url?

Comment: @AHBagheri - `<HOST>/static/<any-random-string>` with or without the trailing slash. I mean `<HOST>/static/<any-random-string>` or `<HOST>/static/<any-random-string>/` . Example `<HOST>/static/123423eere`

Comment: What do you want to happen when user requests /static/abcde?

Comment: @FaisalMemon - I want the content of the `/usr/share/nginx/html/file.html` to be served when user hits `/static/abcde`

Comment: As an experiment try: `location /static { alias /usr/share/nginx/html; index file.html;}`

Comment: @FaisalMemon - I tried that. `/static/xyz/` is working but not `/static/xyz`. When I check the error log, I see `open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/xyz" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: x.x.x.x, server:
 test, request: "GET /static/xyz HTTP/1.1", host: "x.x.x.x"`. It is trying to find the file from the request URL path.

Comment: You might need to add a `try_files $uri $uri/;`

Comment: @FaisalMemon - I tried that. with `alias` I am getting 404. With `root` I am getting 500. Here is my config `       location /static {
         alias   /usr/share/nginx/html;
         index /file.html;
         try_files $uri $uri/;
       }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137008/discussion-between-faisal-memon-and-dany).